# Undefined control sequence error when trying to add \frontmatter and \mainmatter commands

Tags: document-classes, front-matter

I am writing a book, and dividing the book's chapters into separate `.tex` files. I would like to do the same for my appendices, but when I try to do so I get an error message. First, here is my preamble file:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor,fix-cm}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[left=1.50cm,
 right=1.50cm,
 top=1.95cm,
 bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
```

And now, here is the 'main' file: prayerbook:

```
\input{preamble}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\include{toc}

\mainmatter
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5}
\include{chapter6}
\include{chapter7}

\backmatter
\include{appendix7}
\end{document}
```

When I omit the commands `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, etc; I do not get the error message which is the following:

`Undefined control sequence`

at the line with the command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `scrreprt` class (like the `report` class) does not feature `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, and `\backmatter`. If you want to use these commands (be aware that they tinker with page and chapter numbering!), switch to the `scrbook` (or `book`) class. To mimic `scrreprt`/`report`'s headers and page breaking, add the `oneside` and `openany` class options.

Comment: How do I get the appendices to have their own titles? I.e., at the moment, the current appendix has the 'title' of the last chapter still there...

Comment: @MichaelDykes Please ask a new question and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.